# dll: how to make a dll with some cpp classes

Tags: c++, dll

Is it possible to make some cpp classes as a dll file so that I can import this dll and use these classes?
For example, I have four files like this:

```
// A.h
class A
{
public:
virtual void fun();
};
//A.cpp
void A::fun()
{
// do something
}
//B.h
class B : public A
{
public:
virtual void fun();
};
//B.cpp
void B::fun()
{
// do something
}
```

Now, what I want to do is to generate a dll file with these four files above. Then if I have another project, I just import the dll file and use the `A` and the `B` immediately, such as `A a; a.fun(); B b; b.fun();`

Comment: Exposing c++ classes through dll is not very good idea. User of your dll will need to use the same C++ standard libraries (in practice, the same compiler/IDE).

Comment: @AntonMalyshev  hmm, you are right. In fact, here is the reason why I want to use dll like this: I have a series of classes `Exception` (about 20 classes), which inherit the same class. It's kind of like a library of exception. I want to use them for each of my cpp projects. So I am considering that making them as a dll file may be a good idea. If not, can you tell me a better way to avoid copying these 20 classes each time?

Comment: simply include it from common directory (as source code)?

Comment: @AntonMalyshev   hmm... you mean I put them in the common directory? That's sounds nice. There is only one question left: where is the common directory?(I use vs2013)  sry... I am fresh.

Comment: anywhere on the filesystem... you can add .cpp files to the project ("Add -> Existing Item") and to use .h files - add the directory to "Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories" for your project

Comment: @AntonMalyshev   OK. Thanks.